# Reading a big dataset in Tensorflow with google Cloud ML is slow

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to train an LSTM using google Cloud ML. The training dataset are around 600 `tfrecords` files, each one of around 147mb. In total the dataset is around 90GB.

When I train in cloud ml with just a few of those `tfrecords`, starting the training is very quick. But when I use all the `tfrecords`, the job waits around 1 hour in this state:

```
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:18 -0400       master-replica-0                Calling model_fn.                                                                                                                           
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:20 -0400       master-replica-0                Done calling model_fn.                                                                                                                      
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:20 -0400       master-replica-0                Create CheckpointSaverHook.                                                                                                                 
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:22 -0400       master-replica-0                Graph was finalized.                                                                                                                        
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:22 -0400       master-replica-0                Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA                                                
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:22 -0400       master-replica-0                successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero         
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:22 -0400       master-replica-0                Found device 0 with properties:                                                                                                             
ERROR   2018-06-08 14:42:22 -0400       master-replica-0                name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235                                                                              
ERROR   2018-06-08 14:42:22 -0400       master-replica-0                pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0                                                                                                                      
ERROR   2018-06-08 14:42:22 -0400       master-replica-0                totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 11.10GiB                                                                                                  
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:22 -0400       master-replica-0                Adding visible gpu devices: 0                                                                                                               
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:23 -0400       master-replica-0                Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:                                                                             
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:23 -0400       master-replica-0                     0                                                                                                                                      
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:23 -0400       master-replica-0                0:   N                                                                                                                                      
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:23 -0400       master-replica-0                Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10763 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, p
ci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 3.7)                                                                                                                                                                   
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:23 -0400       master-replica-0                Running local_init_op.                                                                                                                      
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:23 -0400       master-replica-0                Done running local_init_op.                                                                                                                 
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:30 -0400       master-replica-0                Saving checkpoints for 1 into gs://teamcore-rnn/discrete_sales_test_0_less_ts/model.ckpt.                                                   
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:37 -0400       master-replica-0                Calling model_fn.                                                                                                                           
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:39 -0400       master-replica-0                Done calling model_fn.                                                                                                                      
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:39 -0400       master-replica-0                Starting evaluation at 2018-06-08-18:42:39                                                                                                  
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:39 -0400       master-replica-0                Graph was finalized.                                                                                                                        
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:39 -0400       master-replica-0                Adding visible gpu devices: 0                                                                                                               
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:39 -0400       master-replica-0                Restoring parameters from gs://teamcore-rnn/discrete_sales_test_0_less_ts/model.ckpt-1                                                      
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:39 -0400       master-replica-0                Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:                                                                             
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:39 -0400       master-replica-0                     0                                                                                                                                      
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:39 -0400       master-replica-0                0:   N                                                                                                                                      
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:39 -0400       master-replica-0                Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10763 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, p
ci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 3.7)                                                                                                                                                                   
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:39 -0400       master-replica-0                Running local_init_op.                                                                                                                      
INFO    2018-06-08 14:42:39 -0400       master-replica-0                Done running local_init_op.
```

Then it runs 2000 steps, and waits and hour in the same state. I'm very new to Tensorflow, but my maybe is because reading the dataset is slow? All the data is in GCS in the same region as the job region.

The code I use to read the dataset is:

```
def tf_record_input_fn(filenames,
                       parser_fn,
                       params,
                       mode=tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN):
    epochs = params.epochs if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN else 1
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
    dataset = dataset.map(parser_fn).filter(filter_empty_labels)
    dataset = dataset.filter(filter_time_series_with_nans)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(params.batch_size * 10).repeat(epochs).batch(
        params.batch_size)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    ts_features_batch, c_features_batch, key_batch, labels_batch = iterator.get_next(
    )

    features_batch = {
        'time_series': ts_features_batch,
        'context': c_features_batch,
        'key': key_batch
    }
    return features_batch, labels_batch
```

Thanks the help and would be happy to give more details if anyone needs it.

Comment: Can you try adding `num_parallel_reads=N` (for some value of `N` e.g. 32 or 64) to the `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` call? The current code is reading one file at a time, which can be quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `num_parallel_reads=N` (for some value of N e.g. 32 or 64) to the `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` call. The current code is reading one file at a time, which can be quite slow.